# Number does not appear in span

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a function that generates a number. I want to put the number into a span element. However, this will not work. The function works and if I put the number into a value box it works. These are the two parts of code pertaining to the question.

Code:

```
document.getElementById('average').innerhtml= averagescore
Average Score:<span id='average'> 0 </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error might be with `.innerhtml`. You should write `.innerHTML` instead.
Note the 'HTML' is all caps.

Comment: That was it! You are a legend. Thanks so much... so frustrating.. spent hours trying to figure out something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = "your value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the **case-sensitivity** of any programming language. JavaScript and jQuery are Case Sensitive Languages.
Two Variables like

```
  var abc;
  var ABC;
```

both are different. So same happens in your case **innerHTML  vs innerhtml**, which are totally different.